# iMac G4: auto playing iTunes music using Automator

Tags: macos, applescript, imac, automator, g4

I have used `Automator` and I have successfully set up events using it and `iCal` before.

I would like to play a playlist from my `iTunes` using `Automator`, the problem is that there is no `"Play Playlist / Song / Item"` Action.

I have tried first adding action `"Find iTunes Items"`, in the `"Find:"` field I chose `"Playlists"`. Subsequently in `"Whose:"` field I selected `"Name"`, `"contains"` and entered the name of the playlist.

The action is confirm after I clicked `"Run"` - it is able to locate the playlist.

The problem is, I don't know what action to add after this, because on my iMac G4 there is no `"Play iTunes Item / Song"` action.

The actions that are available are:

> Delete All iPod Notes
>
> Filter iTunes Items
>
> Find iTunes Items
>
> Get Selected iTunes Items
>
> New iPod Note
>
> Text to Audio File

I find this funny, because there are actions that allow user to select / find / filter the items but no sensible actions available after that (i.e., `"Play"` etc).

Does anyone know why? I am not limiting myself to only `Automator`, if someone knows another way, such as using an `AppleScript`, I would welcome this solution as well.

What I would like to test is: I would like to wake up the G4 and then play the playlist once, stop the music, and then shut down the G4 automatically.

If you happen to know how, please show me the steps. Thanks.

***Addendum:***

If it would not be possible to play songs using `Automator`, I would also welcome a solution such as opening up Safari, go to youTube (with a link I set), play the video there, video stops and then the computer shuts down (the computer doesn't have to shut down right after the video stops; they are 2 independent processes, which means the computer can stay on even after the video stops) using `AppleScript`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't check for your specific requirement, but [Doug's Scripts](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/) is one of the finest iTunes scripting resources available anywhere.
Of course, you can plug any script straight into Automator.

It's fairly safe to say that if you can't find it there, it can't be done.